# IIS 7 keeps old Connection strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I was deploying a mvc 4 project and for some reason IIS doesn't use the connection strings I specified in my web.config. I can copy the web.config file to update the connection strings for iis but not deploy. It wants to keep the connection strings i deleted and replaced the same string in visual studio 2012. Anyone know why it does this?

Comment: Do you have a Web.Debug.config and a Web.Release.config file in your project?

Comment: I did, but I deleted the file. I also deleted the DEBUG and RELEASE Folders and the reattempt it. Once I deploy its like it grabs from somewhere to not override my new changes. I rebuild too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the Problem. I went to the project root\project name\Properties\PublshProfiles\ProfileName.pubxml to edit the code in there. Deleted the ones that had to do with the connections.

```
<PublishDatabaseSettings>
<Objects xmlns="">
<ObjectGroup name=""></ObjectGroup>
</Objects>
</PublishDatabaseSettings>.
```

Anything with the ObjectGroup name="" tag will be deleted.

```
<ObjectGroup Name="">
</ObjectGroup>
```

Items Group:

```
<ItemGroup>
<MSDeployParameterValue Include =""/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Including anything that has the name in the Include="".

```
<ItemGroup>
<_ConnectionStringsToInsert Include="" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Including anything with that area in the Include="". If you do that it will grab the new values. Save the file and will work. At least it worked for me. Save a backup copy of the file and if something goes wrong you will have the original to bring it back.